# Python string format, drop characters if too long

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Currently I have a template for printing out columns in a table to stdout:

```
template = "%-5s%-8s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s"
```

I use it as so to print out my rows

```
print template % row
```

However, some columns in the row go over the amount of characters (e.g., the first string should be limited to the space it's allocated (5) by the template).  Is there a function or specifier I can use with the string format that will chop characters off the end of the string so that it fits the allocated space (or better yet, a length that I specify as the limit).  That is without doing something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(row)):
    row[col] = row[col][0:limit[i]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify precision on the string format.

```
>>> '%.5s' % ('1234567890',)
'12345'
```

Comment: Should be `%5.5s` to apply both minimum and maximum size.